# Safari input file click javascript don't work in a secure event

Tags: javascript, promise, safari

I have an event function who has async task with some promises waiting to end. When I try to open a `<input type="file"/>` after all safari dont open the FileDialog even if the event is trusted

Example:

```html
<html><body>
    <script>
        function myPromise() {
            return new Promise((res, rej) => {
                setTimeout(() => res(true), 1);
            });
        }
        async function btnClick(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            console.log(event.isTrusted);
            try {
                await myPromise();
            } catch (err) {

            }
            document.querySelector("input").click();
            console.log(event.isTrusted);
        }
    </script>
    <input type="file"/>
    <button onclick="btnClick(event)">btn</button>
</html></body>
```

My console return

```
true
true
```

So, the event is trusted until the end but safari doesn't open the Dialog. Is there other rules?

Comment: `await` is syntactic sugar for a callback. The callback runs asynchronously, so you're no longer in the context of the original click event.

Comment: Is there a way to send the "trusted" context to a callback or is it impossible?

Comment: I don't think so, as it would allow code to get around the popup blocker.